# Javascript arguments object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a hard time understanding the arguments object. In this code, what function would arguments be looking at?

```
getAjax('get_info', 'java_array', realVarName, cld.listArray, 0, '',           
'no_restrict', function() {
 show_list(arguments[0], sld);

    if (typeof(postFunc) == "function") {
        postFunc();
    }
 });
```

Comment: Did one of the answers below answer your question?  If so, please select the best answer and click the green checkmark to the left of it.  This will indicate to the community that your question has been answered and will earn both you and the answerer some reputation points.

Answer (score 3):

'arguments' is an inherit variable with any function.  It contains all the parameters passed to a function.  For instance, a function definition may not list any parameters, however an invocation could include 'n' parameters on it.  The function could then still access all of them through the arguments array.

Answer (score 1):

The [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) is an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function.

In your code the `arguments[0]` will primarily be `undefined`

Comment: You have no idea whether `arguments[0]` will be `undefined` or not.  It depends entirely upon what `getAjax()` passed to the callback when it calls it.  If it passes arguments, then `arguments[0]` will certainly have a value.

Answer (score 0):

First off, `arguments` is an object that represents the set of arguments passed to the current function.  It exists automatically inside of every function.  You can read more about it [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

So, in your case, `arguments[0]` will be the first argument that `getAjax()` passes to the callback you passed into it as the last argument when you called `getAjax()`.  So, it depends upon the internal behavior of `getAjax()` which you do not show us.

Let's walk through how your code works:

1. You make a function call to `getAjax()` and pass it a number of arguments.
2. One of those arguments is a callback function (the last argument).
3. When `getAjax()` is doing its job, it will, at some point, call that callback function.
4. When it calls that callback function, it can pass that callback some arguments.
5. Within that callback function the `arguments` object will represent whatever arguments were passed to it by `getAjax()`.
6. So, when (in that callback function), you then get `arguments[0]` and pass it to `show_list()`, you will be passing whatever the first argument was that `getAjax()` passed to your callback.

You could rewrite your code without using the `arguments` object like this by just declaring a named argument for your callback:

```
getAjax('get_info', 'java_array', realVarName, cld.listArray, 0, '',  
  'no_restrict', function(obj) {

    show_list(obj, sld);

    if (typeof(postFunc) == "function") {
        postFunc();
    }
 });
```

In this alternate implementation, you name the first argument to the callback function to be `obj` and use it directly rather than using `arugments[0]`.  Both your implementation and this produce the same result.

---

It is generally better to use named arguments (like the `obj` in my alternate implementation) when you know what arguments are going to be passed to a function as this makes the code more self documenting.  But the `arguments` object can be particularly useful when you don't know how many arguments are going to be passed to a function or when you want to pass whatever arguments were passed to your function to some other function (forwarding or proxying).